# Lucene distinct result

Tags: java, lucene

Please, help me get distinct result by certain field. I tried go by the many way, googled... But can't get ti.

I tried add to HashSet, tried DuplicateFilter. Think about Collector without success. But any result. I use Java, lucene-2.9.3.

Example:

```
some_id   description
1         bbb aaa 
1         aaa ccc
2         aaa ddd
2         fff aaa
```

And if I search by description in result I must get distinct some_id (1,2).

Maybe somebody have solution or have code example.

Thanks to advance.

Comment: Using a hashset, what did you try?

Comment: Er what do you exactly mean by distinct result? That the word turnip might appear in 50,000 documents, but you only want to know if it appears at all?

Comment: I provided example what i want distinct. hashset store unique value. so i get value and add into hashset. in result unique value but really bad in terms of performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very-new (still only a patch) grouping module on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1421 might be relevant here.  It enables you to group all hits according to a certain field.  For example, if you group by "author" then all documents having the same author are in the same group.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Excellent work! Could you please suggest,can I use your patch for version 2.9.3? I don't ready jump to 3.2. Thanks one more.

Comment: Well, I still need to port the patch back to 3.x.  Once that's done, likely (though I'm not sure!) using it in 2.9.x wouldn't be so bad... it's fairly standalone.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no "native distinct" support in lucene.
So you have to write your own logic in java to consolidate the results.